# Open a file with text editor

Tags: windows

On a Windows7 machine I have the need to edit .html files often.  Generally when I left click the behavior should be to open up in the browser (as is the behavior which I don't want to alter).  However I want to be able to open in a text editor from the file.  I would expect I could right click and see an option such as `open with`.  I only see open though as seen here:

[image]

How can I make it so that I can open the file with something like a right click without first changing the file extension to .txt?  I know I could go to the text editor/open/ grab the file.  I'm looking to keep the workflow fast and that slows me down when you do this action hundreds of times a day.

Comment: This should be on SuperUser, but you have to choose "Choose Default Program" and find the text editor you use. Be sure to uncheck "Set as Default" or whatever it's called. This should add the program to the "Open With..." cascade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

There are other text editors but I prefer this one.
It adds a right click context menu option "Open with Notepad++"

Comment: Lot's of great solutions.  I tried them and found I liked this one the most.  I should be using a better text editor than notepad anyway.

Comment: Even if an app doesn't explicitly add a context menu option for your file type, as long as it can open the files you can always add the option yourself via the registry (or any of the various utilities created for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

use total commander and you can set notepad++ for editing html

Answer (score 1):

Using command line utility `assoc` Append something like:

```
.html=txtfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In XP, I used to put a shortcut my editor in the SendTo folder. Not sure if that still works in Win7, though I see SendTo in your screenshot.

Then, any rightclick can do a SendTo editor.